# Cannot run docker redis on windows - permissions denied

Tags: windows, docker, redis, permissions

Enviroment: Windows 10 Home, cygwin, Docker toolbox

Dockerfile

```
FROM redis:latest
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get --assume-yes install vim
RUN mkdir /mnt/redis
VOLUME /var/log
COPY redis.conf /etc/redis/redis.conf
EXPOSE 6937
CMD ["redis-server", "/etc/redis/redis.conf"]
```

Important part from the redis.conf

```
logfile "/var/log/redis.log"
```

Running the command: `docker run -it redis-master`

```
*** FATAL CONFIG FILE ERROR ***
Reading the configuration file, at line 163
>>> 'logfile "/var/log/redis.log"'
Can't open the log file: Permission denied
```

Funny thing is that if I run the container in interactive mode:

```
winpty docker run -it redis-master bash
```

and execute the `redis-server /etc/redis/redis.conf` command there are no permissions problems. What could be the root cause?

Edit.

This is happening in whatever directory I use. For instance:

```
$ winpty docker run -it redis-master

*** FATAL CONFIG FILE ERROR ***
Reading the configuration file, at line 163
>>> 'logfile "/usr/local/etc/redis/redis.log"'
Can't open the log file: Permission denied
```

Comment: Make sure you have correct permissions on `redis.log` file. Or start redis-server by ` sudo /etc/init.d/redis_6379 start`

Comment: The redis.log file does not exist. I don't have such a service on docker redis image.